# Directory is not writable by PHP process

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

Well, it seems to be a common problem that could be resolved just by setting the right permission or atleast 777. But, in my case I'm not able to write any file (using php that runs as `apache` user) in the whole system except in **/tmp**.

Note that /tmp folder has permission of `1777` (sticky bit set). My Apache is running with `user/group = apache/apache` and my website home directory is `/var/www/html`

here is what I have tried so far:

**try 1 :**

Set permission to 1777 and `apache:apache` for `/var/www/html/` and tried to write file using PHP code `file_put_contents("/var/www/html/test_file.txt", "text string");`

I also tried to change user/group to root:root and permissions to 0777

**try 2 :**

Made a copy of /tmp to /tmp2 with exact same permissions i.e: `1777` and `root:root` but not able to write file in `/tmp2`  (using PHP code `file_put_contents("/tmp2/test_file.txt", "text string");`)

**NOTE:** I'm able to write file to `/tmp` with permission `1777` and `root:root` (using PHP code `file_put_contents("/tmp/test_file.txt", "text string");`)

I am using

- CentOS 7.3.1611
- PHP 5.4.16
- Apache/2.4.6

Comment: Sure that PHP runs with the same user id? (Not the PHP version is relavant, but the SAPI - mod_php or FPM). Check with `woami` from within the script. What does error_reporting and Apaches error.log say about it?

Comment: PHP runs with `apache:apache` (cross checked). using `mod_php5`. `whoami` returns "root" because I'm logged in as root user but I'm not executing the PHP command from CLI. Got the following error `failed to open stream: Permission denied`